# How to arrange PHP for loop value?

Tags: php, loops

This is my example of seat list arrangements. I have to show some seat alignment changes.

```
$rows=($data['seat_type']==1)?3:4;
$cols=round($numofseats /$rows) ;
$rowCssPrefix= 'row-';
$colCssPrefix= 'col-';
$seatWidth= 35;
$seatHeight= 35;
$seatCss= 'seat';
$selectedSeatCss= 'selectedSeat';
$selectingSeatCss= 'selectingSeat';
$window_rows = ($data['seat_type']==1) ? array(0,2) :array(0,3);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $seat_w=(in_array($i,$window_rows))?'W':'A';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        $seatNo = ($i + $j * $rows + 1);
        if($seatNo <= $numofseats)
        {
            $className = $seatCss . ' '.$rowCssPrefix .$i.' '.$colCssPrefix .$j;                                      if($j % $cols==0) echo '<br>';
            if(!in_array($seatNo,$booked_seats)) {
                echo'<li class="' . $className.'" style="top:'. ($i *$seatHeight).'px;left:'. ($j *$seatWidth).'px" title="'.$seatNo.$seat_w.'">'.$seatNo.'<input  type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="'.$seatNo.'-'.$seat_w.'"/></li>';
                }else{
                $className .= ' '.$selectedSeatCss;
                echo'<li class="' . $className.'" style="top:'. ($i *$seatHeight).'px;left:'. ($j *$seatWidth).'px">'.$seatNo.'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am getting the result like

```
1  4 7 10
2  5 8 11
3  6 9 12
```

but it should be

```
1  6 7 12
2  5 8 11
3  4 9 10
```

How can I get like this?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the content of the relevant variables

Comment: Reverse the inner loop.

Comment: tip for next time: try to only give us the relevant code. Don't be afraid to change a variable here or there to make it more clear what you mean. Use pseudocode, .. In short: do everything so it's easier for us (readers) to understand your code better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse your seat number calculation if you're calculating a number for an *odd column*.

Change the calculation line to :

```
$seatNo = (($j % 2) > 0) ? (($rows - $i) + ($j * $rows)) : ($i + $j * $rows + 1);
```

What's happening here is, we are controlling if the column is odd or even by `($j % 2) > 0`; then calculating the number accordingly.

So your code should look like this :

```
<?php

$rows=($data['seat_type']==1)?3:4;
$cols=round($numofseats /$rows) ;
$rowCssPrefix= 'row-';
$colCssPrefix= 'col-';
$seatWidth= 35;
$seatHeight= 35;
$seatCss= 'seat';
$selectedSeatCss= 'selectedSeat';
$selectingSeatCss= 'selectingSeat';
$window_rows = ($data['seat_type']==1) ? array(0,2) :array(0,3);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $seat_w=(in_array($i,$window_rows))?'W':'A';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        // If we are on the first (or 3rd, 5th, odd numbers) column, normally continue numbering,
        // But if we are on an even column, reverse the numbering by (($rows - $i) + ($j * $rows)).
        $seatNo = (($j % 2) > 0) ? (($rows - $i) + ($j * $rows)) : ($i + $j * $rows + 1); 
        if($seatNo <= $numofseats)
        {
            $className = $seatCss . ' '.$rowCssPrefix .$i.' '.$colCssPrefix .$j;                                      if($j % $cols==0) echo '<br>';
            if(!in_array($seatNo,$booked_seats)) {
                echo'<li class="' . $className.'" style="top:'. ($i *$seatHeight).'px;left:'. ($j *$seatWidth).'px" title="'.$seatNo.$seat_w.'">'.$seatNo.'<input  type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="'.$seatNo.'-'.$seat_w.'"/></li>';
                }
                else {
                $className .= ' '.$selectedSeatCss;
                echo'<li class="' . $className.'" style="top:'. ($i *$seatHeight).'px;left:'. ($j *$seatWidth).'px">'.$seatNo.'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant line I assume is

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        $seatNo = ($i + $j * $rows + 1);
    }
}
```

In order to get an "reverse effect", simply add an if condition to each odd column.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        if ($j % 2 == 1) $seatNo = (($rows - $i) + $j * $rows );
        else $seatNo = ($i + $j * $rows + 1);
    }
}
```